# компилятор java 8 не пропускает метод по умолчанию в интерфейсе

Tags: java

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: *Java 8* не компилирует код с методом по умолчанию в интерфейсе. При этом работаю точно на 8-й версии: 
*C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\javaw.exe*

```
interface Colorable{
    void colored ();        // абстрактный метод
    default void white(){   // метод по умолчанию. Syntax error on token default
       System.out.println("белый по умолчанию");
    }
}
class Shape implements Colorable {
    public void colored (){
        System.out.println("окрашен цветом");
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape b = new Shape();
        b.colored();
    }
}
```

Использую Eclipse Build id: 20140224-0627

> Syntax error on token "default", delete this token

> The type Shape must implement the inherited abstract method

Консольное сообщение:

```
Colorable.white() 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.
Error: Unresolved compilation problem: at interfDefaultsMetodyPack.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Comment: Почитайте вот [тут](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-default-methods/)

Comment: Спасибо! Но ответа на мой вопрос там нет.

Comment: с помощью `javac` не воспроизводится. В какой среде вы с кодом работаете?

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке можно?

Comment: Использую Eclipse Build id: 20140224-0627
1) Syntax error on token "default", delete this token

2)The type Shape must implement the inherited abstract method 

Консольное сообщение: Colorable.white()Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at interfDefaultsMetodyPack.Main.main(Main.java:14)

Comment: Блин, может Eclipse надо обновить?

Answer (score 2):

Вообще хорошо бы скрин, но я подозреваю, что у вас в настройках билда стоит не 1.8.

От того, что вы указали Java 8 в настройках, не значит, что среда разработки будет билдить с 1.8

Если это Eclipse, то он любит по умолчанию выбирать Java 1.5

Должно быть типо такого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю у вас Eclipse Kepler? Обновите до Eclipse Luna хотя бы.

**UPD:** можно ещё попробовать обновить Kepler: Help -> Install new sofware. А там ввести http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3-P-builds/

Comment: http://ipic.su/jGQB.jpg

Comment: настройки билда проекта: Project Properties -> Java Compiler

Comment: 1.7   http://ipic.su/jGQQ.jpg

Comment: @junior выберите 1.8

Comment: а у меня стоит 1.7 и выставить 1,8 нет возможности почему-то, как такое может быть. Может чтобы Eclipse не поддерживал 1,8?

Comment: @junior у вас Eclipse Kepler? Он вроде не поддерживает Java 8. Поставьте Eclipse Luna хотя бы

Comment: Да Kepler. Спасибо Suvitruf ! Сейчас займусь!

Comment: @junior вообще можно попробовать обновить кеплер. Help -> Install new software. А там введите http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3-P-builds/

Comment: @junior так что, помогло? )